# Is it possible to check if a popup notification was read from the client salesforce?

Tags: notification, popup

We want to disaply custom popup notifications from a scheduler class which runs hourly, but we don't want to spam the client with notifications. Is it possible to check if a popup notification was read from the client salesforce?